# hide() radio button *and* its text label in jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I am going back over a recent project sorting out accessibility issues and was making sure all form elements had labels. Putting the label text into a  tag caused a problem with some kludgy code I had written before.

Basically, if you have a radio button and its label:

```
<label for="zone_r1"><input type="radio" name="zone" id="zone_r1" value="NY" />New York</label>
```

And you use jquery to hide it like so:

```
$('#zone_r1').hide();
```

The actual button is hidden but not the label text. Originally I made a span for the label text and hid that like so:

```
<input id="NY" type="radio" name="zone" value="NY" /><span id="nyTXT">New York</span>
```

and

```
$('#NY').hide();
$('#nyTXT').hide();
```

Any ideas? I prefer not to use the kludge and it may not validate with the span in the label, but maybe I am being overly zealous.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$('#zone_r1').parent().hide();
```

works for me

Answer (score 24):

I think this should work for you

```
$("label[for=zone_r1],#zone_r1").hide();
```

This selects the label with the "for" attribute set to the radio button your looking for, as well as the radio button itself, and hides them both

Answer (score 3):

what about `$('label:has(#zone_r1)').hide();`

Answer (score 2):

For the first radio button, you can hide the actual button and then its [parent](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/parent):

```
$('#zone_r1').hide().parent().hide();
```

For the second case you can hide the button and the "[next](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/next)" sibling:

```
$('#NY').hide().next().hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1.) Define the radio button input without a surrounding label.

2.) Wrap the "option text" (text to the right of the radio button) in a `<span>`.

3.) Use this jQuery statement: `$("input:radio:not(:checked), input:radio:not(:checked) + span").hide();`

This will select the radio button and the text to the right of the radio button and hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Just put 'label' selector in parent:

```
$(':radio[id=zone_r1]').parent('label').hide();
```

See [my jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/A8upf/)

Comment: I don't know why you felt you need to answer this very old and already answered question, and it stuns me that you actually written a selector containing `[id=...]`. That is an ID. You know: `#zone_r1`.

Answer (score 0):

hiding radio button container or TD based on value

jQuery("input[type=radio][value='EU2']").parent().hide();