# How to Hide BR after Radio Button & Label are hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

This answer is about hiding both the radio button and its label, but I also have a `BR` tag following that I need to hide. Currently, there's a blank line.

[hide() radio button *and* its text label in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643704/hide-radio-button-and-its-text-label-in-jquery)

```
$("label[for=sample],#sample").hide();
```

```js
$('label[for=id2],#id2').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" id="id1" name="a" />
<label for="id1">Option1</label><br/>
<input type="radio" id="id2" name="a" />
<label for="id2">Option2</label><br/>
<input type="radio" id="id3" name="a" />
<label for="id3">Option3</label><br/>
```

**SOLUTION** I ended up putting a DIV around the whole line and hiding the DIV.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try give it an `id`?

```
$('br#hide').hide();
```

Something like this.

Comment: No, is that really necessary? BRs are extremely minor elements and one shouldn't have to hack them to fit some task... I was hoping for a more generic solution

Answer (score 1):

Get the `id` of the option and use it to disable the current option and remove the `label` and `br`.

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
  var label = $(this).next('label').attr("for", $(this).attr('id'));
  $(this).hide();
  $(label).next('br').hide();
  $(label).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" id="id1" name="a" />
<label for="id1">Option1</label><br/>
<input type="radio" id="id2" name="a" />
<label for="id2">Option2</label><br/>
<input type="radio" id="id3" name="a" />
<label for="id3">Option3</label><br/>
```

or

```js
  var label =   $('label[for=id2]');
  $(label).next('br').hide();
  $(label).hide();
  $('#id2').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <input type="radio" id="id1" name="a" />
    <label for="id1">Option1</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" id="id2" name="a" />
    <label for="id2">Option2</label><br/>
    <input type="radio" id="id3" name="a" />
    <label for="id3">Option3</label><br/>
```

Comment: Thanks. good option but a bit verbose. I ended up putting a DIV around the whole line and hiding the DIV.